# C++ TCP detect if a client has been disconnected for some seconds

Tags: c++, tcp

In C++, how to detect if a connection to client has been lost for some seconds, lets say 30 seconds. Even if the client dont't respond for more than 30 seconds (for example, the server is waiting for the client to reply), it's not a lost connection as long as the connection is still established.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <vector>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

static int connFd;
void error(const char *msg){
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

void task1 (int connFd){
    //CEstablish timeut connection for client
    struct timeval timeout;      
    timeout.tv_sec = 30;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    if (setsockopt (connFd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&timeout,
                sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
        error("setsockopt failed\n");

    if (setsockopt (connFd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&timeout,
                sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
        error("setsockopt failed\n");  


    cout << "Thread No: " << pthread_self() << endl;
    char test[256];
    bzero(test, 256);
    bool loop = false;
    int n = write(connFd,"I got your message",18);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
    while(!loop){       
        bzero(test, 256);     
        int n = read(connFd, test, 255);
        if (n < 0) {
        //error("ERROR reading from socket"); 

         cout << " ERROR " << endl;
         break; 
        }
        printf("Here is the message: %s\n",test);
        //n = write(connFd,"I got your message",18);
        //if (n < 0) error("ERROR end to socket");
        //string tester (test);
        //cout << tester << endl;     
        //if(tester == "exit")
            //break;
    }
    cout << "\nClosing thread and conn" << endl;
    close(connFd);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int pId, portNo, listenFd;
    socklen_t len; //store size of the address
    bool loop = false;
    struct sockaddr_in svrAdd, clntAdd;

    pthread_t threadA[3];
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        cerr << "Syntam : ./server <port>" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    portNo = atoi(argv[1]);

    if((portNo > 65535) || (portNo < 2000))
    {
        cerr << "Please enter a port number between 2000 - 65535" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    //create socket
    listenFd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if(listenFd < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Cannot open socket" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    bzero((char*) &svrAdd, sizeof(svrAdd));

    svrAdd.sin_family = AF_INET;
    svrAdd.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    svrAdd.sin_port = htons(portNo);

    //bind socket
    if(bind(listenFd, (struct sockaddr *)&svrAdd, sizeof(svrAdd)) < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Cannot bind" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    listen(listenFd, 5);

    int noThread = 0;

    while (noThread < 3)
    {
        socklen_t len = sizeof(clntAdd);
        cout << "Listening" << endl;

        //this is where client connects. svr will hang in this mode     until client conn
        connFd = accept(listenFd, (struct sockaddr *)&clntAdd, &len);

        if (connFd < 0) {
            cerr << "Cannot accept connection" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Connection successful" << endl;
        }
        ///thread t(&task1,connFd);
        threads.push_back(std::thread(task1,connFd));
        //pthread_create(&threadA[noThread], NULL, task1, NULL); 
        noThread++;
    }

    for(auto && t : threads)
        t.join();

    /*for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threadA[i], NULL);
    }*/


}
```

The problem with above code is, if a client don't send any reply to server in 30 seconds, it will be considered as connection lost even the connection is still established.

Comment: This is too broad.  Please narrow it down.  Maybe show your server code that you are having trouble implementing this with.  Also look at `select()` or `(e)poll()` to detect reading timeouts on the socket connection.

Comment: I 've added my server code

Answer (score 1):

After setting the timeout socket options, your reading loop does this:

```
while(!loop){       
    bzero(test, 256);     
    int n = read(connFd, test, 255);
    if (n < 0) {
     cout << " ERROR " << endl;
     break; 
    }
    printf("Here is the message: %s\n",test);
}
cout << "\nClosing thread and conn" << endl;
close(connFd);
```

Now, on timeout `read()` will return `-1`, so you break and `close(connFd);`.  That explains the problem you describe:

> The problem with above code is, if a client don't send any reply to server in 30 seconds, it will be considered as connection lost even the connection is still established.

It's not the socket library closing the connection - it's your `close` call.  Instead, handle `read()` returning `-1` with `errno` or `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` in some other way that doesn't close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem with above code is, if a client don't send any reply to server in 30 seconds, it will be considered as connection lost even the connection is still established.

Only because you're making zero attempt to distinguish between error conditions.

- If you get a read timeout, `errno == EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK`, the connection is still alive, and you should take whatever action is appropriate to a read timeout.
- If you get any other error from `recv()`, *then* you should consider the connection broken.
- If you get any error from `send()` you should *also* consider the connection closed, which you aren't doing at all, you're ignoring it.

Another problem with your code is that you aren't detecting end of stream. If `recv()` returns zero, the peer has disconnected cleanly, and you should close the socket and stop reading.